# SAS Azure Signature did not match

Tags: php, azure, blob

I try to create a SAS to a blob on azure storage in php.
I write the following code:

```
$key ="...";

$end = date('Y-m-d\TH\:i\:s\Z', strtotime('+1 day'));

function getSASForBlob($accountName, $container, $blob, $permissions ,$expiry, $key){
 /* Create the signature */
 $_arraysign = array();
 $_arraysign[] = $permissions;
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = $expiry;
 $_arraysign[] = '/'.$accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = "2015-12-11"; //the API version is now required 
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = '';

 $_str2sign = implode("\n", $_arraysign);

 return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($_str2sign)), base64_decode($key), true));
}

function getBlobUrl($accountName, $container, $blob, $resourceType, $permissions, $expiry, $_signature){
 /* Create the signed query part */
 $_parts = array();
 $_parts[] = 'sv=2015-12-11';

 $_parts[] = 'ss=b';
 $_parts[] = 'srt=' . $resourceType;
 $_parts[] = (!empty($permissions))?'sp=' . $permissions:'';
 $_parts[] = (!empty($expiry))?'se=' .$expiry:'';
 $_parts[] = 'spr=https';
 $_parts[] = 'sig=' . urlencode($_signature);


 /* Create the signed blob URL */
 $_url = 'https://'
 .$accountName.'.blob.core.windows.net/'
 . $container . '/'
 . $blob . '?'
 . implode('&', $_parts);

 return $_url;
 }


$sig = getSASForBlob("cloudviewer","450-423-422-392", "thumbnail.jpeg", "r",     $end, $key);
$url = getBlobUrl("cloudviewer","450-423-422-392","thumbnail.jpeg","o","r", $end, $sig);

echo(json_encode(array('url' => $url, 'sig' => $sig, 'expiry' => $end)));
```

the url result that I received is: https://cloudviewer.blob.core.windows.net/450-423-422-392/thumbnail.jpeg?sv=2015-12-11&ss=b&srt=o&sp=r&se=2016-12-09T17:08:25Z&spr=https&sig=BU6lfFljKLsmK8zPdHny5qRU9XStpE97Pud5vj4biEY%3D

with an authentification error :Signature did not match. String to sign used was cloudviewer r b o 2016-12-09T17:08:25Z https 2015-12-11

I create a SAS directly from Azure and I had the url
https://cloudviewer.blob.core.windows.net/450-423-422-392/thumbnail.jpeg?sv=2015-12-11&ss=b&srt=o&sp=r&se=2016-12-09T17:28:32Z&st=2016-12-08T15:28:32Z&spr=https&sig=EgnmcRSSKol%2BqR2A4aBdFhL9dmkhGJVHOw9W%2BC8%2FTKI%3D
which works and be similar to the first one.

I already try

```
$_arraysign[] = '/blob/'.$accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
$_arraysign[] = $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
```

Do you have any idea ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to generate an account SAS token, as the second example described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#examples-of-sas-uris. Per my understanding, you can only generate a common blob SAS token as the first example mentioned at above article.

Meanwhile, according to the description of [Constructing the Signature String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/constructing-a-service-sas#specifying-the-signature), you missed several parts when generating the signature.

So, please try the following code snippet:

```
function getSASForBlob($accountName, $container, $blob, $permissions ,$expiry, $key){
 /* Create the signature */
 $_arraysign = array();
 $_arraysign[] = $permissions;
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = $expiry;
 $_arraysign[] = '/blob' .'/'.$accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = "2015-12-11"; //the API version is now required 
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = '';
 $_arraysign[] = '';

 $_str2sign = implode("\n", $_arraysign);

 return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($_str2sign)), base64_decode($key), true));
}

function getBlobUrl($accountName, $container, $blob, $resourceType, $permissions, $expiry, $_signature){
 /* Create the signed query part */

 $_parts = array();
    $_parts[] = (!empty($expiry)) ? 'se=' . urlencode($expiry) : '';
    $_parts[] = 'sr=' . $resourceType;
    $_parts[] = (!empty($permissions)) ? 'sp=' . $permissions : '';
    $_parts[] = 'sig=' . urlencode($_signature);
    $_parts[] = 'sv=2015-12-11';
    $_parts[] = 'rscd=';


 /* Create the signed blob URL */
 $_url = 'https://'
 .$accountName.'.blob.core.windows.net/'
 . $container . '/'
 . $blob . '?'
 . implode('&', $_parts);

 return $_url;
 }

$sig = getSASForBlob(AZURE_ACC_NAME,AZURE_CONTAINER, BLOB, "r", $endDate, AZURE_PRIMARY_KEY);
$url = getBlobUrl(AZURE_ACC_NAME,AZURE_CONTAINER,BLOB,"b","r", $endDate, $sig);
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I am trying now to do the same, but for the entire container, so I the "b" (resourceType) by a "c" for container; but it doesn't work.