# Azure copy blobs from one storage account to another in the same subscription using rest API

Tags: php, rest, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to copy blob from one storage account to another storage account in the same subscription using Rest API and PHP. I am able to do a copy blob from one container to another in the same storage account using the below code

```
<?php    
$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
$account_name = "accname";
$destcontainername = "destcontainer";
$blobname = "blob.png";
$sourcecontainer = "sourcecontainer";    
$account_key = "asdf";

$canonicalizedHeaders = "x-ms-copy-source:https://".$account_name.".blob.core.windows.net/".$sourcecontainer."/".$blobname."\nx-ms-date:$date\nx-ms-version:2015-04-05";
$canonicalizedResource = "/$account_name/$destcontainername/$blobname";

$arraysign = array();
$arraysign[] = 'PUT';                     /*HTTP Verb*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Encoding*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Language*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-MD5*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Type*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Date*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Modified-Since */  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-None-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Unmodified-Since*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Range*/  
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedHeaders;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedResource;    /*CanonicalizedResource*/

$stringtosign = implode("\n", $arraysign);

$signature = 'SharedKey'.' '.$account_name.':'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringtosign, base64_decode($account_key), true));

$endpoint = 'https://'.$account_name.'.blob.core.windows.net';
$url = $endpoint.'/'.$destcontainername.'/'.$blobname;

$headers = [
    'x-ms-copy-source:https://'.$account_name.'.blob.core.windows.net/'.$sourcecontainer.'/'.$blobname,
    "x-ms-date:{$date}",
    'x-ms-version:2015-04-05',
    'Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata',
    'Accept-Charset:UTF-8',
    'Content-Length:0',
    "Authorization:{$signature}"
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);        

echo '<pre>';print_r($response);
```

I would like to know if i have to use the same copy blob rest API to accomplish it. If yes than what will be the `$canonicalizedHeaders` and  `$canonicalizedResource` and resquest rest API. I am able to do copy blob from one storage account to another using the powershell command below

```
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -DestContainer $destinationContainerName -DestContext $destinationContext -SrcBlob $vhdName -Context $sourceContext -SrcContainer $sourceSAContainerName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the same code for copying blobs across storage accounts as well. While `$canonicalizedResource` remain the same, you would need to include the URL of the source blob in `x-ms-copy-source` header in `$canonicalizedHeaders`.

One important thing to keep in mind is that the source blob URL that you specify in `x-ms-copy-source` header must be publicly accessible. What that means is that if you take that URL and paste that in browser's address bar, you should be able to access the blob. If the source blob container's ACL is `Blob` or `Container`, then you can simply specify the blob URL (`https://sourceaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/sourceblobcontainer/sourceblobname`) however if the source blob container's ACL is `Private` then you would need to create a `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` on the source blob with at least `Read` permission and use the SAS URL for this header's value.

Another thing to understand is that copying across storage accounts is an asynchronous operation. So when the code above executes successfully, the blob copy operation is queued. You must check if the copy operation has completed before deleting source blob or making any changes to that otherwise the copy operation will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gaurav. Here i am trying to copy the vhd files from the OSdisk and data disk from the source storage account to the destination storage account. Will the canonicalizedResource  and canonicalizedHeaders still be the same?

Comment: Yes. Conceptually the process is the same whether you copy in the same account or acorss accounts. In both cases you will be calling `Copy Blob` REST API. The values will change based on what you're trying to copy and where i.e. source and target blob information. HTH.

Comment: I do not want to make my blobs publicly accessible, so in this scenario should i generate the SAS token for both the source and the destination storage account, if i am doing so than how should i be passing the SAS token in the curl headers.

Comment: You would need to create SAS URL for the source blob and include that in your 'x-ms-copy-source' header.

Comment: In fiddles request headers for copy blob operation i found this `x-ms-copy-source:https://sourceSAName.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/vhdName?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=sdfdsfsfddsf&se=2017-04-27T06:55:57Z&sp=r`. Here i can find few other parameters like sv, sr, se and sp. What are these parameters used for

Comment: These are the parameters for `Shared Access Signature`. For example, `se` means when your SAS will expire. You can read more these parameters here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/constructing-a-service-sas.

Comment: Hi @MAS, If you wish to create SAS URL by using PHP script, you can refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044373/sas-azure-signature-did-not-match/41052480#41052480) for details.