# Azure SAS token for copy blob operation issue

Tags: php, azure, authentication, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy blob form one storage account to another, as per the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494650/azure-copy-blobs-from-one-storage-account-to-another-in-the-same-subscription-us/) i am able to generate `shared access signature (SAS)` for `x-ms-copy-source`. Now my problem is i am unable to pass through the authentication of copy blob operation it says "`AuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request`".

I am using the below code to generate SAS token as well as authentication signature for copy blob. Can someone help me in fixing the issue

```
$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
$account_name = "souraccount";
$desaccname = "desaccount";
$destcontainername = "descontainer";
$blobname = "abc.png";
$sourcecontainer = "sourcecontainer";
$source_account_key = "asdfghjkl";
$destination_account_key = "poiuytr";

$expiry = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", time() + 30000);
$sig = getSASForBlob($account_name,$sourcecontainer, $blobname, "b", "r", $expiry, $source_account_key );
$url = getBlobUrl($account_name,$account_name,$blobname,"b","r",$expiry,$sig);

$canonicalizedHeaders = "x-ms-copy-source:".$url."\nx-ms-date:$date\nx-ms-version:2015-04-05";
$canonicalizedResource = "/$account_name/$sourcecontainer/$blobname";

$arraysign = array();
$arraysign[] = 'PUT';                     /*HTTP Verb*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Encoding*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Language*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-MD5*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Type*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Date*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Modified-Since */  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-None-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Unmodified-Since*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Range*/  
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedHeaders;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedResource;    /*CanonicalizedResource*/

$stringtosign = implode("\n", $arraysign);

$signature = 'SharedKey'.' '.$desaccname.':'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringtosign, base64_decode($destination_account_key ), true));

$endpoint = 'https://'.$desaccname.'.blob.core.windows.net';
echo $url = $endpoint.'/'.$destcontainername.'/'.$blobname;

$headers = [
    "x-ms-copy-source:$url",
    "x-ms-date:{$date}",
    "x-ms-version:2015-04-05",
    "Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata",
    "Accept-Charset:UTF-8",
    "Content-Length:0",
    "Authorization:{$signature}"
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);        

echo '<pre>';print_r($response);

function getSASForBlob($accountName,$container, $blob, $resourceType, $permissions, $expiry,$source_account_key ){
     /* Create the signature */
     $_arraysign = array();
     $_arraysign[] = $permissions;
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = $expiry;
     $_arraysign[] = '/' . $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = "2015-04-05"; //the API version is now required
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';

     $_str2sign = implode("\n", $_arraysign);

     return base64_encode(
     hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($_str2sign)), base64_decode($source_account_key ), true)
     );
}

 function getBlobUrl($accountName,$container,$blob,$resourceType,$permissions,$expiry,$_signature){
     /* Create the signed query part */
     $_parts = array();
     $_parts[] = 'sv=2015-04-05';
     $_parts[] = 'sr=' . $resourceType;
     $_parts[] = 'sig=' . urlencode($_signature);
     $_parts[] = (!empty($expiry))?'se=' . urlencode($expiry):'';    
     $_parts[] = (!empty($permissions))?'sp=' . $permissions:'';

     /* Create the signed blob URL */
     $_url = 'https://'
     .$accountName.'.blob.core.windows.net/'
     . $container . '/'
     . $blob . '?'
     . implode('&', $_parts);

     return $_url;
 }
```

Comment: One issue I see in your code is that you're using same key (`$account_key`) for both source & destination accounts.

Comment: @GauravMantri i have modified the code in the post with `$source_account_key` and `$destination_account_key` . It still fails to authenticate

Comment: There's one more thing I noticed. In your request headers, you're setting `Content-Length` header's value as `0` (which is correct) however you're not keeping this value as empty in `$arraysign[]`. Can you please try setting the value here as `0` as well and retry your request?

Comment: One good way to debug this kind of issue is parse the response. Normally you would see the string to sign used by the server and then compare that with your string to sign to see how both differ. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri As u said in your previous comment i have kept my `$arraysign[ ]` value to empty for `Content-Length` now i get an error `CannotVerifyCopySourceServer failed to authenticate the request`

Comment: We're definitely making some progress :). Now I believe there's an issue with your SAS URL. Please try by changing the following line `$_arraysign[] = '/' . $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;` to `$_arraysign[] = '/blob/' . $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;` in your `getSASForBlob` function.

Comment: Yes i changed it but still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri it works now. The change u asked me to do `$_arraysign[] = '/blob/' . $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;`  fixed the issue

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that things are working OK for you. I'm curious to know why you're implementing REST API directly when there's a PHP SDK for Azure Storage.

Comment: @GauravMantri Apart from azure cloud storage i am working on other services of Azure like compute, so for compute there is no PHP SDK available. So i thought of working on REST API's itself as the Azure PHP SDK does not cover most of the services of Azure

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find below complete working code to copy blob from source storage account to destination storage account. Solution given by *Gaurav Mantri* in the comments section fixed my issue

```
$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
$account_name = "saccname";  // Source Storage acoount name
$desaccname = "daccname";    // destination Storage acoount name 
$destcontainername = "vhd"; // destination Container name
$blobname = "sblob.vhd";    // source blob name
$sourcecontainer = "vhd";  // source container name
$source_account_key = "sdfsdfdsf";
$destination_account_key = "safdsf";

$expiry = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", time() + 30000);
$sig = getSASForBlob($account_name,$sourcecontainer, $blobname, "b", "r", $expiry, $source_account_key);
$xms_copy_source_url = getBlobUrl($account_name,$sourcecontainer,$blobname,"b","r",$expiry,$sig);

$canonicalizedHeaders = "x-ms-copy-source:".$xms_copy_source_url."\nx-ms-date:$date\nx-ms-version:2015-04-05";
$canonicalizedResource = "/$desaccname/$destcontainername/$blobname";

$arraysign = array();
$arraysign[] = 'PUT';                     /*HTTP Verb*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Encoding*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Language*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-MD5*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Type*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Date*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Modified-Since */  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-None-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Unmodified-Since*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Range*/  
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedHeaders;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedResource;    /*CanonicalizedResource*/

$stringtosign = implode("\n", $arraysign);
$signature = 'SharedKey'.' '.$desaccname.':'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringtosign, base64_decode($destination_account_key), true));

$endpoint = 'https://'.$desaccname.'.blob.core.windows.net';
$url = $endpoint.'/'.$destcontainername.'/'.$blobname;

$headers = [
    "x-ms-copy-source:$xms_copy_source_url",
    "x-ms-date:{$date}",
    "x-ms-version:2015-04-05",
    "Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata",
    "Accept-Charset:UTF-8",
    'Content-Length:0'
    "Authorization:{$signature}"
];


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);        

echo '<pre>';print_r($response);


function getSASForBlob($accountName,$container, $blob, $resourceType, $permissions, $expiry,$source_account_key){
    /* Create the signature */
    $_arraysign = array();
    $_arraysign[] = $permissions;
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = $expiry;
    $_arraysign[] = '/blob/' . $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = "2015-04-05"; //the API version is now required 
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';

    $_str2sign = implode("\n", $_arraysign);

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($_str2sign)), base64_decode($source_account_key), true));
}

 function getBlobUrl($accountName,$container,$blob,$resourceType,$permissions,$expiry,$_signature){ 
     /* Create the signed query part */
        $_parts = array();
        $_parts[] = (!empty($expiry)) ? 'se=' . urlencode($expiry) : '';
        $_parts[] = 'sr=' . $resourceType;
        $_parts[] = (!empty($permissions)) ? 'sp=' . $permissions : '';
        $_parts[] = 'sig=' . urlencode($_signature);
        $_parts[] = 'sv=2015-04-05';
        $_parts[] = 'rscd=';

     /* Create the signed blob URL */
     $_url = 'https://'.$accountName.'.blob.core.windows.net/'. $container . '/'. $blob . '?'. implode('&', $_parts);

     return $_url;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Gaurav Mantri wrote in a comment:

> We're definitely making some progress :). Now I believe there's an issue with your SAS URL. Please try by changing the following line
>
> ```
> $_arraysign[] = '/' . $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> $_arraysign[] = '/blob/' . $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
> ```
>
> in your getSASForBlob function.