# Authentication error for Copy blob snapshot from one storage account to another using string to sign

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am working on azure rest api using PHP. Here i am trying to copy the snapshots from one storage account to another using the below code. I know there is some mistake in my sas token code. I am getting the auth error it says *`AuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request.`*

Can anyone help out in fixing the issue

Code to generate sas token for copy snapshot

```
$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
$source_acc_name = "sourceaccname";
$destination_acc_name = "destinationaccname";
$dest_containername = "destcontainername";
$blobname = "ijk.png";
$sourcecontainer = "sourcecontainer";
$source_account_key = "sdsfdsfdsf";
$destination_account_key = "dsfdsgfd";

$expiry = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", time() + 30000);
$sig = getSASForBlob($source_acc_name,$sourcecontainer, $blobname, "b", "r", $expiry, $source_account_key);
$url1 = getBlobUrl($source_acc_name,$sourcecontainer,$blobname,"b","r",$expiry,$sig);

function getSASForBlob($accountName,$container, $blob, $resourceType, $permissions, $expiry,$source_account_key){
     $snapshotdatetime = "2017-03-24T10:51:06.345679Z";
     $_arraysign = array();
     $_arraysign[] = $permissions;
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = $expiry;
     $_arraysign[] = '/'.$accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob.'?snapshot='.$snapshotdatetime;
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = "2015-04-05";
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_arraysign[] = '';
     $_str2sign = implode("\n", $_arraysign);

     return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($_str2sign)), base64_decode($source_account_key), true));
}

 function getBlobUrl($accountName,$container,$blob,$resourceType,$permissions,$expiry,$_signature){
    $snapshotdatetime = "2017-03-24T10:51:06.345679Z";
     /* Create the signed query part */
    $_parts = array();
    $_parts[] = 'sv=2015-04-05';
    $_parts[] = 'sr=' . $resourceType;
    $_parts[] = 'sig=' . urlencode($_signature);
    $_parts[] = (!empty($expiry)) ? 'se=' . urlencode($expiry) : '';
    $_parts[] = (!empty($permissions)) ? 'sp=' . $permissions : '';

     /* Create the signed blob URL */
    $_url = 'https://'.$accountName.'.blob.core.windows.net/'. $container . '/'. $blob . '?snapshot='.$snapshotdatetime. implode('&', $_parts);

    return $_url;
 }
```

I am using the below copy to copy the snapshot

```
$canonicalizedHeaders = "x-ms-copy-source:".$url1."\nx-ms-date:$date\nx-ms-version:2015-04-05";
$canonicalizedResource = "/$destination_acc_name/$dest_containername/$blobname";

$arraysign = array();
$arraysign[] = 'PUT';                     /*HTTP Verb*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Encoding*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Language*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-MD5*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Type*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Date*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Modified-Since */  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-None-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Unmodified-Since*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Range*/  
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedHeaders;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedResource;    /*CanonicalizedResource*/

$stringtosign = implode("\n", $arraysign);

$signature = 'SharedKey'.' '.$destination_acc_name.':'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringtosign, base64_decode($destination_account_key), true));

$endpoint = 'https://'.$destination_acc_name.'.blob.core.windows.net';
$url = $endpoint.'/'.$dest_containername.'/'.$blobname;

$headers = [
    "x-ms-copy-source:$url1",
    "x-ms-date:{$date}",
    "x-ms-version:2015-04-05",
    "Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata",
    "Accept-Charset:UTF-8",
    "Content-Length:0",
    "Authorization:{$signature}"
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);        

print_r($response);
```

Comment: Can you tell us the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Please check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516762/azure-sas-token-for-copy-blob-operation-issue. We discussed exact same issue there.

Comment: Yes i followed the same post to copy the blob from source to destination account and its working fine. But when i try to do the same using copy snapshots from source to destination storage account i am getting an auth error

Comment: Try changing the following line `$_arraysign[] = '/'.$accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob.'?snapshot='.$snapshotdatetime;` in `getSASForBlob` to `$_arraysign[] = '/blob/'.$accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob.'?snapshot='.$snapshotdatetime;`. See if this fixes the problem.

Comment: Now i am getting a different error `CannotVerifyCopySourceServer failed to authenticate the request.`

Comment: Coolness! We're getting somewhere now :). Can you please ensure that the source blob & snapshot exists? Also try to remove `'?snapshot='.$snapshotdatetime;` from above.

Comment: Yes blob and snapshot exists, as you said i removed '?`snapshot='.$snapshotdatetime;` from `getSASForBlob` function i am getting the same error

Comment: One more thing. I also noticed that you're specifying `Content-Length:0` in request headers. Please make sure you include the same value in `$stringtosign` as well (2nd code block).

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: Its working now i had made a silly mistake my destination storage account key was wrong.

Comment: Awesome! Can you post your working code as an answer so that other folks can benefit from it. Thanks.